# WshShell.run and major problems in Windows 7 

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, batch-processing

This is a VBScript that I would like to improve. I would like four things :

1) Add a line that would rename the extension cleanup.dll to cleanup.exe, so as it can be called by the WshShell.run and executed (hidden).

2) The way it is written just below, the script opens two screens : the screen of the cleanup.exe and a blank screen, which should be hidden for the user and it is not what is happening ! How to hide the second screen ? I want to run it invisibly (the user cannot close or manipulate the second screen. It will be closed via code that is inside the cleanup.exe).**NOTE : The code below works perfectly in Windows XP, but not on Windows 7. How to make it work in all Windows platforms ?

**VBSCRIPT "Second.vbs"**

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
objFSO.MoveFile "cleanup.dll" , "cleanup.exe" 
WshShell.Run "c:\cleanup.exe", 0, TRUE
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

**BATCH "Master.bat"**

```
@echo off
wscript Second.vbs
exit /b
```

**3) Is there a good and reliable software to convert from VBS to EXE ?**

**4) The other problem I am having is that the command line below does not yield results.Must I use the second pard of the code below instead ? Why ??**

Suppose that my Batch file is in located in drive f:\

If I double click on it, my screen should be then populated with information extracted from the TXT file, which actually resides in drive c:\

```
@echo off
set DRV=C:\August\MyProgram
cd\
cd %DRV%
type test.txt & pause>nul


@echo off
set DRV=C:\August\MyProgram
cd\

c:

cd %DRV%
type test.txt & pause>nul
```

Thank you in advance for the explanations and solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why run with batch, vbscript is more powerfull and offers more controll.

about the visible console window
`WshShell.Run "c:\cleanup.exe", 0, TRUE` should hide the console while running and waits before continuing
Make sure you start your script with wscript.exe, not cscript.exe and don't use any wscript.echo

Renaming a file

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.MoveFile "cleanup.dll" , "cleanup.exe"
```

about the batch cd, practice this in a console window
cd never changes to a drive, only to another map, drive: changes the active drive

```
d: => d:\>
c: => c:\> (so now if you are on c:\)
cd d:\test =>c:\ (changes your active map on d: to d:\test but since your c: drive is still the active drive you see nothing happening)
d: => d:\test (change drive to d:, you do see that the active map on drive d: is d:\test (at least with the default prompt)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanations on the drive changes. I was testing the "file renaming" part and could not make it work. Could you please edit my VBS code above with yours (hidden file + renaming)? Have you tested? Kind regards.

Comment: yes i tested, but a " was lost in editing, corrected it, the hiding also works (no influence on what the exe itself does though), have you checked that you run wscript.exe, not cscript.exe ?

Comment: It is working fine but the CMD screen "master.bat" does not close now. Basic question but if the cleanup is in drive F:\Clean;  the Second.vbs is in drive K:\Second and the master.bat is in drive H:\Master, how should I modify the above codes? Note : I have implemented your codes in my question and I updated question 3

Comment: don't understand your problem, start the vbscript by itself from a shortcut for example, or start the batch minimized with "start.exe" /b,  not from a batch and why would you convert the vbs to exe ? btw, you can set wscript as the default VM for vbscript with /E and /S see wscript /? for details

Comment: The cleanup is in another drive, not in the drive that the VBS will run. Thanks for your comments